# SMTP protocol + port numbers, IMAP, POP3

Tags: smtp, port, imap, pop3

I need to provide a `SMTP` email service to a network and correctly configure the ports.

I understand `SMTP` uses port `25` over `TCP`, but have also read that SMTP is mainly used to transfer mail between mail servers and not the individual clients. Would either `IMAP` or `POP3` be needed to send from the client to the server on port `993` or `995`? or is there another port or way?

What other ports are needed to send an email via `SMTP`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more specific requirements.

Comment: I would just like to understand more on which ports are used to communicate over SMTP and weather or not another protocol is needed to be used from client to server, hope this is okay, thanks.

Comment: Look up SMTP submission servers.